# Fade in background url when fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, load, waitforimages

I am trying to improve the loading event on my photo blog, but I am a bit disapointed.

All my images are dynamicly add to a `background: url()` of `.cover-gallery div`. I use [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin but when the page loaded I have the usual glitch of image process loading.

I would only fade in my `.cover-gallery div` when they are fully loaded.

```
// Hide images by default
$('.cover-gallery').find('div').addClass('fadeOut');

// Detect when images are fully loaded
$('.cover-gallery').find('div').waitForImages({
  finished: function() {
    $('.loader').addClass('fadeOut');
    $('.cover-gallery').find('div').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
  },
  waitForAll: true
});
```

You can see it in live at [blog.jeremybarbet.com](http://blog.jeremybarbet.com/).